# Drag paths in Raphaeljs when rotation or scale is changed

Tags: javascript, path, drag-and-drop, draggable, raphael

I have a question regarding the Raphael JS library (version 2.0.0) and the ability to drag my paths around. I get the drag-function to work with my path, but when I am changing the scale or rotation of my path, the drag-function loses all control and my elements flies everywhere.

I have tried to use the draggable-library, but as I can see it does not support Raphael 2.0.0 and therefore I can't use it, since I am using Catmull-Rom curveto in my code which is a new feature in Raphael 2.0.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```
paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("holder"), 768, 1024);

var startPath = function () {
  this.ox = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("x") : this.attr("cx");
  this.oy = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("y") : this.attr("cy");
},
movePath = function (dx, dy) {
  var trans_x = (dx)-this.ox;
  var trans_y = (dy)-this.oy;

  this.translate(trans_x,trans_y);
  this.ox = dx;
  this.oy = dy;
},
  upPath = function () {
  // nothing special
};

drawing = "M152.854,210.137c-9.438-64.471,22.989-102.26,124.838-96.551s244.094,41.985,152.664,151.667C338.926,374.934,162.761,277.813,152.854,210.137z";

shape = paper.path(drawing);;
shape.translate(0,0);
shape.scale(1,1);

shape.attr({
  'stroke': '#000000',
  'fill': 'blue',
  'stroke-width': '5',
});

shape.drag(movePath, startPath, upPath);
```

So, this is working, but as soon as i add for example the following code it is not working:

```
shape.scale(2,2);
shape.rotate(90);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raphael 2.0 uses SVG matrix and the translate method only adds translate to the current matrix. You should look into using absolute coordinates instead, like:

```
movePath = function (dx, dy) {
  var trans_x = (dx)-this.ox;
  var trans_y = (dy)-this.oy;

  this.transform("T"+[trans_x,trans_y]);
  this.ox = dx;
  this.oy = dy;
}
```

Maybe this.attr("x") and this.attr("cx") is also a matrix converted point and then you need to get the absolute value using:

```
x = this.matrix.e;
y = this.matrix.f
```

Note that above code is not tested.

Comment: Thanks for this input! I just had to change a little part of your code to get just what I wanted:

    this.transform("…T"+[trans_x,trans_y]);