# Drag and drop a set of paths in Raphael.js when using a viewbox

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, raphael, viewbox

I have a question regarding drag and drop with Raphaël 2.1.1. I am able to successfully drag a path around when I use the code available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837831/drag-paths-in-raphaeljs-when-rotation-or-scale-is-changed).

However, when I add the viewbox method, the drag and drop functionality does not work as well as it normally would. I feel that the solution would be to compensate for it in the transform but I am new to using SVG and have no idea on what to tweak.

In my code the starting parameters for my paper are 800 X 800. When I use a viewbox, I use the parameters 1200 X 1200.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need to compensate your dx and dy values with the increase ratio of your viewbox.

For a paper of 800 X 800, you if you are using a viewbox of 1200 X 1200, then you multiply your dx and dy values in the move method by 1.5. That is all there is to it.

Everything is easy once you know how.